# Why i cant import modules in JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

why i cant import my class when i am using the app.js in my html file?

In the console is always `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Html snippet

```html
<!-- Scripts -->
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="assets/plugins/bs/bs.js"></script>
<!-- APP -->
<script src="assets/js/SmashTheHamster.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Elements.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Session.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

code in app.js (there is this error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`) and yes i exported my modules with `export defaut MODULE`

```
import elements from "./Elements";
import SmashTheHamster from "./SmashTheHamster";
```

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the script tag using `type="module"`